# Javascript hide element(s) and put something else in place

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, visibility

I have a small question.

For a task we have to make in Javascript I need some help.

We have a text and some words we give an id (html). In javascript we have to make a function that when it's clicked, all the words with the id become invisible. I know, I can do this too. But there's one more thing. If we put the word invisible, it has to become clear there was a word there before! It would look like a fill-in text, if you can understand.

Now I have this:

```
function toggle_woordjes() {
var e = document.getElementsByClassName('invul');
for(i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
    if (e[i].style.display !== ''){
        e[i].style.display = '';
    }
    else {
        e[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
```

}

}

The code doesn't work properly anymore because I changed it so much that I can't get back to the original.

I hope you people can help me.

Sorry that my English isn't the best!

Cheers

Comment: Instead of making the words invisible, how about simply changing its color to match the background color? This may work if I have understood your question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the parent's background is only 1 color (no design nor pattern), you may write something like the following.

```
object.style.backgroundColor="same color as parent"
```

however if the background is more complex:

```
function toggle_words() {
    var doms = document.getElementsByClassName('class_name');
    for (var i = 0; i < doms.length; ++i) {
        var domStyle = doms[i].style;
        if (domStyle.visibility === 'visible') {
            domStyle.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
        else {
            domStyle.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }
}
```

I use visibility instead of display because the elements stay in the DOM, thus the user knows there was something before.

Comment: It helped really wel! Thanks! Although var visibleStyle = e[i].style.visibility; this didn't work for some reason but I replaced visibleStyle just by e[i].style.visibility and it works now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, I think that you need to make it `e[i].style.display = 'none';` rather than empty string in order to make them disappear (and change the test accordingly).

But it sounds like that wasn't your real problem but rather displaying text to indicate that there was an element there. I would suggest having a `<div>` with class 'invul' that contains 2 other `<div>` elements: 1 is the text to display if the real content is invisible and the other is the real content. Something like this:

```
<div class="invul">
    <div class="msg">Word was here</div>
    <div class="word">I am the real message</div>
</div>
```

Then make them disappear and reappear as needed.